How to add items to a list and reorder them in flutter?
I have been trying to add items to a reorderable list (i.e. add ListTiles to a list, and then reorder the ListTiles in that list).
All of the examples I have seen detail doing one (often creating a "todo" list like https://medium.com/flutter-community/simple-to-do-list-app-in-flutter-26abc50db741) or the other (rearranging items in an existing list: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html), but not both.
I managed to combine them when using a dialog box (which is limited in what it can do), but not when using a Modal Bottom Sheet.
So this works:
      body: ReorderableListView(
        onReorder: reorderData,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
        children: _tasks.map((Task task) {
          return TaskItem(
              task: task,
              onTaskChanged: _handleTaskChange,
              editTask: _handleTaskEdit,
              removeTask: _deleteTask);
        }).toList(),
      ),

But this doesn't:
      body: ReorderableListView.builder(
        onReorder: reorderData,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
        itemCount: _tasks.length,

        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Card(
            key: Key('$index'),
            color: Colors.lightBlue[100],
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(_tasks[index]['taskName']),
              subtitle: Text(_tasks[index]['taskType']),
              trailing: SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                      onPressed: () => _showForm(_tasks[index]['id']),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                      onPressed: () => _deleteItem(_tasks[index]['id']),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },

      ),

Any suggestions?
